# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment - Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, fatal-error

I have an app in java that should connect to Microsoft SQL Server.. I use JRE 1.8 and sqljdbc4-2.0.jar.. When I try to run :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006f41dd27, pid=8404, tid=8960
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x5dd27]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions   of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\eclipse\workspace\Website\hs_err_pid8404.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I searched for this bug online but I couldn't find anything..

Here's the code I use :

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Mydatabase;integratedSecurity=true";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception("Driver Not Found");
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your code? We can't tell you anything from this.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you can't use `integratedSecurity=true`. Perhaps you should look for another JDBC driver.

Comment: Does D:\eclipse\workspace\Website\hs_err_pid8404.log show any additional information?

Comment: I would suggest using the [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site [Building the Connection URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx) you might have a problem in your connection string.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Mydatabase;integratedSecurity=true
```

Should be :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Mydatabase;integratedSecurity=true
```

(note instanceName, not instance)

Also....

For optimal connection performance, you should set the portNumber when you connect to a named instance. This will avoid a round trip to the server to determine the port number. **If both a portNumber and instanceName are used, the portNumber will take precedence and the instanceName will be ignored.**

Hope that helps